# SWRevealViewController not show status bar push from Appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am trying to push `SWRevealViewController` from `appdelegate` at first, the status bar is shown only temporary and after loading the viewController its not appearing.

Here is my code and I am using swift:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let sw = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "revealControllerStoryboard") as! SWRevealViewController
self.window?.rootViewController = sw

let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searchViewStoryboard") as! SearchViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationController)
sw.pushFrontViewController(navigationController, animated: true)
```

How to show the status bar permanently?
and heres the pict

[image]
[image]

Comment: first status bar is shown but covered or completely not shown ???

Comment: You have to push the instantiateViewController for every page.

Comment: @Sh_Khan completely not shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

somehow adding this line make the status bar show again

Answer (score 0):

Try this **EDIT**

```
let frontNavigationController:UINavigationController
let rearNavigationController:UINavigationController
let revealController = SWRevealViewController()
var mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()

let menuTable = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "MenuViewController")as! MenuViewController
let homepage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

frontNavigationController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: homepage)
rearNavigationController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: menuTable)
rearNavigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

revealController.frontViewController = frontNavigationController
revealController.rearViewController = rearNavigationController
revealController.delegate = self
mainRevealController  = revealController

UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window?.rootViewController = mainRevealController
```

Comment: where do you put this code in app delegate or in view controller ?

Comment: Second code try to put on AppDelegate & first code will put on view controller

Comment: did you mean  application.isStatusBarHidden = false ? because i cant seem to found application.statusBarHidden

Comment: You can find application.isStatusBarHidden = false in your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions this method

Comment: its seem not working with the second code at app delegate still not showing the status bar

Comment: still not working after i tried your edited answer it did show temporarily but after that it completely dissapear